# Is this Mereologically motivated Replacement scheme, a theorem schema of ZF-Regularity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Define:* $x=\{y \mid \varphi(y)\} \equiv_{def} \forall y \, (y \in x \leftrightarrow \varphi(y))$

provided that $x$ doesn't occur free in $\varphi$

*Define:* $(\bigcup b : \varphi(b)) \text { exists} \equiv_{def} \exists x : x=\{y \mid \exists b: \varphi(b) \land y \in b\}$

provided that $x$ doesn't occur free in $\varphi$

**M.Replacement:** $\forall a\forall b \forall c \forall d \, (\varphi(a,b) \land \varphi(c,d) \to [a=c \leftrightarrow b=d]) \\ \to \\ 
 (\{a \mid \exists b \, \varphi(a,b)\} \text{ exists} \leftrightarrow    (\bigcup b :\exists a \, \varphi(a,b))\text{ exists})$

Where $\varphi$ may have parameters.

This principle, which is Mereologically motivated, can prove: Singletons, Pairing, Set Union, Power sets, nonempty Separation, and Replacement. It doesn't prove existence of an empty set though.

> Is this principle a theorem scheme of $\sf ZF-Regularity$?

If this is the case, then one can axiomatize $\sf ZFC$ by these five principles: Extensionality; Foundation; M.Replacement; Infinity; Choice.

Comment: Your definition of $\{y \in b | \varphi\}\text{ exists}$ is quite unconventional, since it doesn't mean what the usual notation means. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Trebor, I've seen this tradition written many times, but I don't remember where. I agree that on the face of it, it gives the impression that $b$ is free over the whole expression, while as I defined, it is not. But anyhow since I defined it, then this need not be the concern anymore.

Comment: @Trebor, I've edited to a more familiar notation I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\varphi(a,b)$ describes a one-to-one relation, then if there exists a set $A=\{a \mid \exists b \, \varphi(a,b)\}$, then clearly we can use the formula $\exists a \in A: \varphi(a,b)$ in Replacement from $A$, to get the set $B=\{b \mid \exists a \, \varphi(a,b) \}$, and from Set union we get $\bigcup B$ which is the wanted set on the right hand.

For the opposite direction, let $C= (\bigcup b: \exists a \, \varphi(a,b))$, then each $b$ such that $\exists a \, \varphi(a,b)$ is a subset of $C$, and so it is an element of $\mathcal P (C)$, and so we can use $\exists a \, \varphi(a,b)$ and Separate on $\mathcal P(C)$, to get the set $B=\{b \mid \exists a \, \varphi(a,b)\}$, then use the formula $\exists b \in B \, \varphi(a,b)$ in Replacment from $B$ to get the $\{a \mid \exists b \, \varphi(a,b)\}$. $\square$